# Next.JS: How can i find the generated static files for a route?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, vercel, next.js14

When next.js generated a static page (i.e using the `getStaticProps`), is it possible to get the static files and able to host just that route on a seperate server maybe using serve command etc. ?

For example, my route is `https://<domain>/myUserPage` <- a route dynamically generated using getStaticProps
now i want to get the HTML, etc. and other static files and host them on other server i.e serve only client side static files